# Random variable, diagonalization type argument?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

Let $d_j$ be i.i.d. random variables, with$$P(d_j = 0) = P(d_j = 1) = {1\over2}.$$Define$$X = 0.d_1d_2 \dots = \sum_{j = 1}^\infty {{d_j}\over{2^{j}}}.$$I know how to show that $X$ is uniformly distributed on $[0, 1]$. My question is, how do I define $Y_1, Y_2, \dots,$ independent random variables each with a uniform distribution on $[0, 1]$? Do I use some sort of diagonalization sort of argument?

Comment: What are $Y_1, Y_2, ...$? Do you want to calculate something specific?

Comment: I want to show that if $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ is the unit interval with Lebesgue measure on the Borel subsets, then we can find independent random variables $X_1, X_2, X_3, \dots$ defined on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$, each normal mean zero, variance $1$...

Comment: Hint: Split $\mathbb N$ into countably many disjoint subsets $N_i$ and use $\{d_j\mid j\in N_i\}$ to build $Y_i$.

Comment: Read: ...countably many disjoint *infinite* subsets...